# How can I send notification in same time everyday - OneSignal

Tags: android, onesignal

How can I send a push notification to my android phone with OneSignal
example I want to send automatic message at 6.00am everyday.

How can I implement it?

Comment: Using the [Delivery section](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-delivery) Will be a start of where to go and maybe creating a automatic task on your server that every day at noon make that call

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by running **cron job** on server side.
It's so simple : just set cron to start everyday on 6 am and run the command to send push notif message to all fcm_tokens which are registered already.

I suggest you to queue the messages for getting better result.